# Bind params in multiple foreach loops

Tags: php, yii2, bindparam

How can I bind params in multiple foreach loops?
With `?` SQL output is wrong

```sql
'%term%'SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE (LOWER(`name`) LIKE '\\' ESCAPE '%second_term%') OR (LOWER(`name`) LIKE '\\' ESCAPE )
```

```php
$attributes = $this->attributes;
$searchTerms = explode(' ', $term);

foreach (Arr::wrap($attributes) as $attribute) {
    $sql = new Expression("LOWER(`{$attribute->getAttribute()}`) LIKE ? ESCAPE ?");

    foreach ($searchTerms as $searchTerm) {
        $searchTerm = mb_strtolower($searchTerm, 'UTF8');
        $searchTerm = str_replace("\\", $this->getBackslashByPdo(), $searchTerm);
        $searchTerm = addcslashes($searchTerm, "%_");

        $attribute->isPartial()
            ? $query->orWhere("$sql")
                    ->addParams(["%{$searchTerm}%", '\\'])
            : $query->orWhere([$attribute->getAttribute() => $searchTerm]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what i assume is currently the previous loops value is concatenated along with the next value when using `addParams()` ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam addParams (https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#addParams()-detail) - Adds additional parameters to be bound to the query.

Comment: i know that i am talking about the problem you are having when using it in for loop

Comment: Do you realize that if you do `orWhere("$sql")` then there is no point in wrapping it in `yii\db\Expression`? Beacause at that point `__toString()` method is called and the expression is passed to `orWhere` as string.